# Selenium - check href of a link

Tags: xpath, selenium, playframework, css-selectors

I'm using play framework and the selenium that is used within {selenium} tags.

So far I have this:

```
verifyText(css=a:contains('Remove'), ' href="/node/remove?uuXXid=yftest5"')
```

However, that just returns the text Remove which is the label of the link.

I would like to get the href.  So I tried:

```
css=a:contains('Remove')@href
```

But that then complains saying element is not found.

I've also seen about `GetAttribute` but I cannot seem to find any combination that works within this playframework selenium markup environment.

Unfortunately the documentation on the play site is very poor!

I've also tried this xPath, but whilst it seems to find the element it returns '':

```
//a[text()='Remove']/@href
```

Answer (score 0):

In IDE you can do it this way

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyAttribute</td>
    <td>//div[@id='top-stories']/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a@href</td>
    <td>/2013/10/24/twitters-ipo-could-raise-14-billion</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>//div[@id='top-stories']/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a@href</td>
    <td>href</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${href}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

webdriver python

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='top-stories']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/a/img").get_attribute("src"), '/2013/10/24/twitters-ipo-could-raise-14-billion")
```

Hope this helps